# I set a key in django's request.session , but has no effect

Tags: mysql, django, session, python-2.7

I set jobfile key in session below:

```
def getjoblist(request):
    joblist = request.GET.get('job')
    jobliststr = joblist[0:-1]
    request.session['jobfile'] = jobliststr
    return HttpResponse("ok\n")
```

and I check the mysql database, rows is increment, but when I test the key ,It shows the key is not in session:

```
if request.session.has_key('jobfile'): # return False;
```

I didn't know why?

Comment: Are you sure Django ran into this method?

Comment: Seems that you are using database-backed sessions. Make sure: 1. Django has ran into this method. 2. `'django.contrib.sessions'` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. 3. You have ran `manage.py migrate` to install the single database table that stores session data.

Comment: @Dinever  I use session in the wrong way, so get that result.

Comment: Then feel free to answer your own question, and set it as a final answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why, first I use shell command 'curl' to request, and session is saved. Then, I use browser to request , and session is also saved. But, this two session is not the same, because   session is different between users. So, I can't get the key.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to save the session after adding the new key

```
request.session['jobfile']
request.session.save()
```

Comment: but in here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/,no mention of the need of save.

Comment: @lanyun: That's true. I'd try it anyway.